# CakePHP 3.0 - How do I log an error on transactionals that don't use execute?

Tags: mysql, transactions, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to run a function that goes something like this:

```
$records->connection()->transactional(function () use ($records, $entities) {
    foreach ($entities as $record) {
        $records->save($record, ['atomic' => false]);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to check and see if this transactional threw an error, or is there just something inherently wrong with running a transactional in this fashion vs. executes?

The end goal is to update a set number of entities, but update none if an error was thrown. The functions above are abstract enough to allow different aspects of the entity to be changed, so this method was played around with rather than specific executes to allow for ease of saving through entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConnectionInterface::transactional()` will issue a rollback in case the callback returns `false` or throws an error (which is being re-thrown afterwards).

Quote from the docs:

> [...]
>
> The transactional method will do the following:
>
> - Call `begin`.
> - Call the provided closure.
> - If the closure raises an exception, a rollback will be issued. The original exception will be re-thrown.
> - If the closure returns `false`, a rollback will be issued.
> - If the closure executes successfully, the transaction will be committed.
>
> [...]

**[Cookbook > Dabase Access & ORM > Database Basis > Using Transactions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions)**

> [...]
>
> Returns `mixed` The return value of the callback.
>
> [...]

**[API > \Cake\Datasource\ConnectionInterface::transactional()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionInterface.html#_transactional)**

So exceptions are already covered, you can simply catch them, and the return value is the value that is returned from your closure, so all you may additionally need is to return `false` from your closure in case `Table::save()` calls are failing.

Comment: Ah - the return false is what I lacked. I tried logging the return value of the closure but it was null, and that's likely why.